# Complex Analysis books/online resources for self study

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I am looking to self-study complex analysis. While I have a good grasp of undergraduate real analysis (sequences, series, analysis of single-variable functions, point-set topology), I have forgotten most of the complex analysis I have studied. The book we used was by Bak and Newman, which I didn't like much.
Are there any **good books or online resources** available?

Comment: Yes, but I'm also looking for online resources. MOOCs etc.

Comment: 'Visual Complex Analysis' by 'Tristan Needham'